# invoke Action with unknown type parameter (Action<any>)

Tags: c#

I am creating an API, and my goal is to expose a method that can be invoked like this:

```
Library.AddCallback<string>(Type.ChatMessage, GotMessage);

private void GotMessage(string message) {
    //...
}
//or
Library.AddCallback<int>(Type.Number, GotNumber);

private void GotNumber(int number) {
    //...
}
```

The type `<int>`, `<string>` can be any type.

In the library, the method looks something like this:

```
public void AddCallback<T1>(object type, Action<T1> callback) {
    //...
}
```

The problem is that I somehow want to first save the callback outside of the method call (in a list) and then later be able to call it.

What I ideally want to do is to first cast it to an object to be able to store it in a `List<object>` and then cast it back to `Action<T1>`. However it seems like it is impossible to save T1 to a variable (except by doing `typeof(T1)` which denies me to use it to cast it back).

Example of how I would like to call it (where I got `type` and `data` from a list):

```
((Action<type>)callback)(data)
```

Comment: Does your `Library` class properly handle/know that `data` should be an `int` in some cases and a `string` otherwise? EDIT: How does it convert its `data` into whatever arbitrary type?

Comment: No, ideally the library should be unaware of which type T1 is. As a last resort, I could just do if statements checking if data is string and in that case cast it to Action<string>. However, this would result in a lot of unnecessary code as I'd also like to support Action<T1, T2>, Action<T1, T2, T3> etc. I will probably have to support at least 15 different types.

Comment: I will get the data from the user as well (the library is for networking, and this code listens for data sent from a client)

Comment: Does it work whereby if the `data` is an `int`, it would call _all_ `int` callbacks? Or if it is a `string` it would call _all_ string callbacks? How do you know which callbacks to call when?

Comment: You can do things like putting all callbacks into an `object[]` and then pulling one out, casting it to `Delegate` and calling `DynamicInvoke` on it with a bunch of arguments -- this will resolve everything at runtime (and throw if you made any mistake). But what is the use case? Why do you need to store the callbacks in a list?

Comment: Sorry, List was a simplified example, I will store it in a custom type of list that will allow me to get the correct one. Will check out DynamicInvoke aswell, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure how `data` is typed. Assuming it's type `object` for now, you can decompose the `Action<T>` to `Action<object>` and perform a cast in them:

```
private List<Action<object>> Callbacks = new List<Action<object>>();

public void AddCallback<T1>(object type, Action<T1> callback) 
{
    Callbacks.Add((data) => callback((T1)data));
}

public void FireCallback(object data)
{
    Action<object> callback = GetCallback();
    callback(data);
}
```

EDIT: You've already marked it as an answer, but here's another implementation that stores the callbacks in a typed set.

A `CallbackHandler` stores the typed list of callbacks:

```
public class CallbackHandler<T> : ICallbackHandler
{
    private List<Action<T>> Callbacks = new List<Action<T>>();

    public void AddCallback<T>(Action<T> callback)
    {
        Callbacks.Add(callback);
    }

    public void Callback(object data)
    {
        T typedData = (T)data;
        foreach(var callback in Callbacks)
            callback(typedData);
    }
}

public interface ICallbackHandler
{
    void Callback(object data);
}
```

Then your higher level `Library` has something like this:

```
private Dictionary<Type, ICallbackHandler> AllCallbacks = new Dictionary<Type, ICallbackHandler>();

public void AddCallback<T>(Action<T> callback) 
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    ICallbackHandler handler;
    if (!AllCallbacks.TryGetValue(type, out handler))
    {
        handler = new CallbackHandler<T>();
        AllCallbacks[type] = handler;
    }
    CallbackHandler<T> typedHandler = (CallbackHandler<T>)handler;
    typedHandler.AddCallback(callback);
}

public void FireCallback(object data)
{
    Type type = data.GetType();
    ICallbackHandler handler;
    AllCallbacks.TryGetValue(type, out handler);
    if (handler != null)
        handler.Callback(data);
}
```

This is assuming that the type of `data` determines which callback(s) to fire. If you need to put one more level on it (based on `Type.ChatMessage` or `Type.Number`) it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Thanks, works great! Cool trick to use (data) => callback((T1)data, been thinking about this for a while but that idea did never come across me.

Comment: The second solution looks actually looks even better, I've never used a fully typed class before so might look into that.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using your idea of a behind-the-scenes casting from "object" to the desired type in a somewhat similar case, where a received object is deserialized and thus the type is not known at compile time. At first I thought this would imply problems with handling derived types, when the processing method specifies the base type as parameter. But then I added a bit of code to test for the derived type not being known in the list or array, and if not then testing if type.BaseType is known, and using that if so. Works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
List<object> callbacks = new List<object>();

public void AddCallback<T1>(object type, Action<T1> callback)
{
    this.callbacks.Add(callback);
}

public IEnumerable<Action<T>> GetCallbacks<T>()
{
    return this.callbacks.OfType<Action<T>>();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
// Sample callbacks
static void Foo(int i) { Console.WriteLine("Foo {0}", i); }
static void Bar(string s) { Console.WriteLine("Bar {0}", s); }

AddCallback(null, (Action<int>)(Foo));
AddCallback(null, (Action<string>)(Bar));

foreach (var callback in GetCallbacks<int>())
{
    callback(42); // only calls Foo
}
```