# How can you explicitly cast a variable of type 'object' to satisfy a multi-typed generic constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

We have a generic extension method which works only for objects that supports both the INotifyCollectionChanged and IEnumerable interfaces.  It's written like this:

```
public static class SomeExtensions
{
    public static void DoSomething<T>(this T item)
    where T : INotifyCollectionChanged, IEnumerable
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

The following compiles fine since `ObservableCollection<string>` implements both interfaces and thanks to the 'var' keyword, knownType is strongly typed:

```
var knownType = new ObservableCollection<string>();
knownType.DoSomething();
```

However, we are trying to call this from a ValueConverter.  The problem is the incoming value is of type `object` and even though we can test that the passed-in object does implement both interfaces, we can't figure out how to explicitly cast it so we can call that generic extension method.  This doesn't work (obviously)...

```
object unknownType = new ObservableCollection<string>();
((INotifyCollectionChanged,IEnumerable)unknownType).DoSomething();
```

So how can you cast an object to multiple interfaces so you can call the generic?  Not even sure it's possible.

Comment: That's a fantastic question. You can of course use `dynamic` but I doubt that's what you are after.

Comment: You could use reflection.

Comment: Avoiding dynamics, the only ways to do it will involve types that satisfy both interfaces.  You could use a class or interface that implements both interfaces.  But, as you've realized, there's no way in c# to represent the type of a variable that satisfies two unrelated interfaces.

Comment: Could you refactor `DoSomething()` so that it doesn't rely on both interfaces. Perhaps break out the dependencies into 2 methods? Its hard to imagine why a method would need both change notifications and enumerability of the same collection.

Comment: @Mike, the reason is because originally we were specifically targeting ObservableCollection<T> but then we realized in the implementation we didn't really care what T was, nor that it was an ObservableCollection.  All we cared about was that it was enumerable and that it supported collection change notifications, so we changed it thinking why not support *any* objects provided they implement both interfaces.  Then we ran into this issue.  I'm starting to think we should just target 'Object' then test for the types inside and validate the parameter then rather than trying to cast beforehand.

Comment: "... and it's strongly typed thanks to the var keyword". Come again?

Comment: Exactly what I said. Using var implicitly creates a strongly-typed variable the same as if you had explicitly specified the class name.  string foo = "Hello" and var laa = "Hello" both produce strongly-typed string variables foo and laa.  But that's besides the point of the question.

Comment: Yes, well, um, I'd be more inclined to say " ... and it's strongly typed _despite use of the var keyword_". Ah well, to each his own. :-)

Comment: Seriously though, neglecting "var", I must admit I'm having trouble understanding your question. First you say "new ObservableCollection<string>()" is strongly typed, then you say that for your particular usage it isn't. I'm interested in this because I'm wondering if your problem can be solved by basing your DoSomething() method on a non-generic interface and behind-the-scenes casting from "object" to the desired type. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854956/invoke-action-with-unknown-type-parameter-actionany/16855094#comment48379329_16855094

Comment: 'Despite' doesn't make sense there because var is *why* it's strongly typed, not something that happened despite it.  That's akin to saying 'Despite writing 'string foo = "abc";' foo is a string.' Var is implicit. String is explicit. But they are both strongly typed because of their definitions.  And as for your other comment, of course you can do a non-generic version, but that breaks the usage of the extension method for known types since it would have to extend 'object' meaning you could explicitly call it in invalid scenarios.  It looks like 'dynamic' is the only way around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way I can think to do this would be `dynamic`. However, because extension methods don't play nice with `dynamic` (see blelow), you'll have to reference the extension method explicitly.

```
Extensions.DoSomething(unknownType as dynamic);
```

**EDIT** As a warning aginst the gotcha I ran into here, note that calling the method with explicit `dyanmic` as the type argument (via `DoSomething<dynamic>`) will *not* work - it causes compile errors when trying to match against multiple constraints. In addition, when not using multiple constraints, this results in the `dynamic` resolving based on the passed variable's compile-time type, *not* the runtime type.

This will result in a call to `Extensions.UnknownType<dynamic>`, the `dynamic` of which will resolve at runtime - meaning it'll use the fully derived type of the given parameter. As long as this parameter implements the desired interfaces, off you go.

Be wary as, like much `dynamic` code, this could encounter issues that won't be seen until runtime. Use sparingly!

If you make multiple calls with the same generic paremeters, you might be better off adding a generic helper method in your converter and then calling *that* using `value as dynamic`

**Addendum**:

When using `dynamic`, anything called against the `dynamic` object will attempt to resolve as a member of the given type at runtime, but will *not* look up Extension Methods, since they inherently exist in a completely different class, often a different assembly.

Comment: Not sure I follow the reasoning here because as you said, dynamics don't call extension methods.  And if you're going to go this way anyway, why not just extend 'Object' and test for the two interfaces explicitly inside, throwing an ArgumentException if needed?  Of course I'd recommend against extending 'Object' so going that route, I'd probably just drop 'this' and make it a regular static method anyway for the above reasons.

Comment: Extension methods, when called explicitly, can be used with `dynamic` objects. While more verbose, this does allow for calling methods which have multiple interface constraints

Comment: I think you're going to get the vote because we ended up going with this, even though as I expected, there's no way to do a hard cast.  That said, I think your second solution (after the 'or') is wrong.  That didn't compile for us.  Did you get that one to work?  If so, can you provide an example?  If not, just remove it and I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Running the code, it does *compile*, but the second option results in the binding being done based on the variable's type, *not* the actual runtiume type, thus pretty much negating the intention in the first place. I'll update accordingly.

Comment: Actually, @Aravol, I'm going to call you on that.  The second case (since deleted) doesn't compile because of the type constraints. If there were no constraints, it does, and perhaps your 'EDIT' then applies, but this question is specifically because of type constraints and with them, if you use <dynamic>(value) as opposed to (value as dynamic) you get the following compile-time error... "Error 2 The type 'dynamic' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' [...] There is no implicit reference conversion from 'dynamic' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'"

Comment: @Marquel I admit I was only testing in a limited way, and hadn't gotten to making those type constraints before realizing it was improperly using the `dyanmic` anyway. I'll keep this one in mind next time this issue come up!

Comment: If you update your 'EDIT' to call this out, I'll give you the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to retrieve a delegate to the right method using MethodInfo and delegates.

The following solution **does not** use *dynamic*, but a little of *Reflection*.
Basically the method does the following operations:

1. Retrieves a delegate of the method you want to call, but for another, known type.
2. Retrieves from it the generic method definition.
3. Then retrieves the *MethodInfo* for the object's type.
4. Calls the extension method by Invoking the final *MethodInfo*.

The **_Placeholder** class is the known type used to fetch the initial delegate, but you can use any other type that satisfy the generic constraints.

This way you will also have Compile-time checking of extension method's name and its contraints.

A good approach would also cache the final MethodInfo (or Delegate), to avoid repeating expensive calls.

---

```
private sealed class _Placeholder : INotifyCollectionChanged, IEnumerable
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

static void Test(object obj)
{
    if ((obj is INotifyCollectionChanged) && (obj is IEnumerable))
    {
        var typeObject = obj.GetType();

        // Retrieve the delegate for another type
        Action<_Placeholder> _DoSomething = SomeExtensions.DoSomething<_Placeholder>;
        // Retrieve the generic definition
        var infoTemp = _DoSomething.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
        // Retrieve the MethodInfo for our object's type
        var method = infoTemp.MakeGenericMethod(typeObject);

        // Call the extension method by invoking
        method.Invoke(null, new[] { obj });

        //If you can return the delegate, you can try the following:
        //var typeDelegate = typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(typeObject);
        //var action = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeDelegate, method);
        //((Action<_Test>)action)(obj as _Test);
    }
}
```